# How to make sure three.js is mobile friendly

Tags: javascript, mobile, web, three.js

This last week I have been building myself a personal website.

It has some information in semi transparent divs in front of an animation of a spinning cube. (pretty basic stuff right?)

Well here's the rub, I noticed that examples at threjs.org/examples run on mobile well and despite my best efforts to do things likewise my site doesn't appear to be rendering threejs components on mobile.

So far I have tried a few things:

First to ensure that I was rolling back gracefully from webgl I included detector in index.html and use

```
 renderer =  Detector.webgl ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ alpha: true }): new THREE.CanvasRenderer({ alpha: true });
```

to declare my threejs renderer.

Second I ensured that my code was well factored with an init, animate, and render method.

Third I included stats.js (as the examples do) modifying my html css and js accordingly.

And yet nothing I seem to do is working!

The page as it stands now renders fine on the computer and responds well to window resize events, but on a phone nothing appears in the background.

As far as I can see I am going about things in the same manner that the examples do and yet I am not getting the mobile performance.

your help is greatly appreciated!

Oh, the site is here: [krewn.github.io](http://krewn.github.io) and consists of only three files each fewer than 80 lines.

Edit: after some changes (declairing undeclaired variables and adding "use strict"; the 3d renders on desktop and mobile except for mobile Mozilla, which is strange because the examples at threejs.org work on mobile Mozilla...

Comment: I see no 3d in chrome on pc and get the error **Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode**

Comment: but I do see 3d in Firefox and no errors

Comment: I have made some changes and while the page renders in chrome still no dice on mobile, although the mobile preview tool in chrome indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Like @2pha mentioned in his comment your site isn't working:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Block-scoped declarations (let, const, function, class) not yet supported outside strict mode

try to add:

```
"use strict";
```

at the top of all your `.js` files, I bet then it will run fine on both Chrome and mobile phone.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot edit any of the remote sources, and adding "use strict"; to the top of prettyGaphics was ineffective.  I noticed that container and stats were undeclared so I added them to the let list. Everything seems to be behaving fine on chrome, but the cube still does not render on mobile...

Comment: @kpie There must be something you missed. Like you said all examples run fine on mobile so there must be something else in your code that breaks your viewer. Maybe a Fiddle could help to locate it?

Comment: yeah unfortunately it doesn't run on js fiddle... The current state of the page is still here http://krewn.github.io