# My three.js application is not running on mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile, three.js

I am running iOS 13.7 on an iPhone and all the [three.js examples](https://threejs.org/examples/) I tried (including the ones on fat lines and orbit controls) work flawlessly on my mobile device.

However, I do not seem to be able to get my own code running on mobile, see the [source code](https://github.com/BaranCanOener/BaranCanOener.github.io) and the [uploaded website](https://barancanoener.github.io/) for reference. It works on both Edge and Chrome on my Windows computer.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35933855/how-to-make-sure-three-js-is-mobile-friendly) suggested adding "use strict"; to all .js files, which I did even for the imported modules, but to no avail.

Any ideas or hints on what could be breaking my JavaScript code for mobile?

This how the modules were included in hopf.js:

```
import * as THREE from './three.module.js';
import { OrbitControls } from '/OrbitControls.js';
import { LineMaterial } from './LineMaterial.js';
import { LineGeometry } from './LineGeometry.js';
import { Line2 } from './Line2.js';
import { GUI } from './dat.gui.module.js';
import Stats from './stats.module.js'
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        body { margin: 0; }
        canvas { display: block; }
    </style>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type = "module" src = "hopf.js"></script>
</body>
```

The init-function:

```
function init() {

    // Camera
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.001, 1000);
    camera.position.x = -3;
    camera.position.y = 0;
    camera.position.z = 0;
    camera.lookAt(0,0,0);

    // Orthographic camera, to focus on the 2-sphere base space
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var scale = 3;
    //orthCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera( window.innerWidth / - 2, window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight / 2, window.innerHeight / - 2, 0.001, 1000);
    orthCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(-aspect*scale, aspect*scale, 1*scale, -1*scale, 0.001, 1000);
    orthCamera.position.set(5,5,10);
    orthCamera.lookAt(0,0,0);

    // Scene for fiber projections
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Scene for the 2-sphere base space
    orthScene = new THREE.Scene();

    // Objects
    baseSpace_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,30,30);
    baseSpace_material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xfafafa});
    baseSpace_material.transparent = true;
    baseSpace_material.opacity = 0.5;
    baseSpace = new THREE.Mesh(baseSpace_geometry,baseSpace_material);
    baseSpace.position.x = 4.5;
    baseSpace.position.y = -1;
    orthScene.add(baseSpace);

    // Renderer
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight );
    renderer.autoClear = false;

    // Controls
    controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    stats = new Stats();
    document.body.appendChild(stats.dom);

    initGui();

    baseSpaceCircles.push(new baseSpaceCircle(0, 2*Math.PI, 10, defaultRotation, new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0), 0.0));

    onWindowResize();
    render();
}
```

Comment: Might be worthwhile to add some code to show how you have included `three.js` and used it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion- added index.html, the inclusion block and the init-function setting it all up in hopf.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your website isn't running on Firefox either. If you open the console, you'll see the error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: private fields are not currently supported

which is happening on the line that uses `#distanceToCenter_radians;` because the `#` symbol is a reserved key to declare a private field. I recommend you remove it to improve browser compatibility. Looking at the support table, [private fields don't work on Firefox and any Safari below 14.0](https://caniuse.com/?search=private%20field)

### EDIT

After fixing the Firefox bug, I tested it on Safari, and I ran into this error in the console:

[image]

This is because your `baseSpaceCircle` class uses public class fields, which are not supported by Safari until version 14.0+.

```
// These class variables won't work:
class baseSpaceCircle {
    distanceToCenter; // <- Safari 13 thinks this is a class method
    distanceToCenter_radians;
    circumference;
    // ...
}
```

I tried to initialize them with a starting value, but that didn't work either:

```
class baseSpaceCircle {
    distanceToCenter = 0;
    distanceToCenter_radians = 0;
    circumference = 0;
    // ...
```

this approach yielded this error...
[image]
... which led me to [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60026651/safari-unexpected-token-expected-an-opening-before-a-methods-paramet). In essence, your app is using pretty advanced JavaScript, and many of its features are not yet implemented by all browsers, including Safari in both iOS and MacOS. Private fields, public class fields, and all those are basically a compatibility nightmare because they're so new, and browsers take some time to catch up.

### Solution 1:

Declare all those variables inside your constructor with `this.xxx`:

```
class baseSpaceCircle {
    constructor(distanceToCenter, /*...*/) {
        this.distanceToCenter;
        this.distanceToCenter_radians;
        this.circumference;
        this.pointCount;
    }
    //...
```

Works in Safari!
[image]

### Solution 2:

I strongly recommend you use a transpiler [like Babel, which reads your cutting-edge code, and compiles it into older JavaScript that *all* browsers still support](https://babeljs.io/). This takes the headache out of programming with cool things like classes, arrow functions, async/await, etc.

Comment: Thank you! That was an artifact from when I tried to encapsulate all class properties, but gave up for the sake of keeping this little script simple. I removed the privatization symbol and it now runs on Firefox on my machine - but still not luck on iOS.

Comment: @Paul I added a second part, debugging in Safari, and explaining how to fix it.

Comment: Thank you very much! I would upvote it again if I could. I am not very experienced in JavaScript, meaning I don't know the specifications and the state of the language/compatibility well, so I just copied over what concepts I knew from C++ etc. That will help me to be more mindful of which code actually works in which environment. EDIT: Debugging it on Safari unfortunately wasn't an option for me since they got rid of it on Windows machines- so again, thank you for helping me with that piece of work.

Comment: @Paul Yeah, testing Safari is a bit tough. I ended up having to buy a used 7-year old MacBook from 2013 to test iPhone and other Mac environments. If you need a cheaper alternative, you could [test on BrowserStack](https://www.browserstack.com/test-on-safari-browser), which runs your website remotely on their devices, so you don't have to buy every device imaginable!

Comment: this may seem like a stupid Q, but is threejs mobile friendly in 2022?

Comment: @oldboy Yes. Feel free to visit the examples page on a mobile device to test the performance of different effects https://threejs.org/examples/

Comment: @Marquizzo One last Q: Are there any guides anywhere on how I can port a model from blender or .glb dropped into the threejs editor to an actual webpage?